# Creating a Method Called ValidString to validate user inputs

Tags: c#

I am completely new to this coding thing and am completely lost. I've been asked

"Create a method called ValidString that will return true/false if the string that is passed in is not null and not empty. You should use the IsNullOrEmpty or the IsNullOrWhiteSpace methods of the string class to check if the string is empty."

Currently I have

```cs
public static bool ValidString(string value)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if this is right or not as whenever I input anything that's a blank input it continues like nothing is wrong.

I apologize if this is something super simple, I'm completely inexperienced when it comes to coding and being on a deployment with trash internet doesn't help.

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review Community, our goal here is to help you improve your code by making insightful observations about the code that is written. The code must be working as intended already. We don't answer `How to ...` questions because that means the code isn't working as intended yet. There is a site that can help you, Please read [Where can I get help?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A string with a white space `" "` has a length of 1 and is therefore not empty. A string `s` is empty when it is not null and when `s.Length == 0`.

Your method is correct; however, you can simplify it:

```cs
public static bool ValidString(string value)
{
    return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(value);
}
```

`IsNullOrEmpty` returns `true` when you want to return `false` and vice versa. Therefore you can invert the Boolean result with the NOT operator `!`.

Usage example:

```cs
string input;
while (true) {
    input = GetUserInput();
    if (ValidString(input)) {
        break;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Your input is not valid. Try again!");
}
Process(input);
```

Comment: Ok so what I have is good, but can be simplified. I just couldn't tell if it was working or not. I need to call and use this method in other methods, and if it returns false it needs to spit an error and ask for the users input again.